# How to display active and non active Submenus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Hei
Iam new to jquery iam trying to display submenus after clicking on Menu .- for example when I select the top menu it display all its submenus . but when i click one of its submenus  other submenus disappear . For example i clicked on "Furniture" it opened its two submenus which are "Deko" and "Fancy" . When i click on "Deko" other submenus disappear and just contents of deko display

How to resolve this. Please help
 Here is my code

```
    <ul id="application-menu">
      <li class="dropdown">Furniture
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" />Deko</li>
          <li><a href="" />Fancy</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown">Tables
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" />Table1</li>
          <li><a href="" />Table2</li>

      </li>
    </ul>

<style type="text/css">

  li.dropdown ul
  {
    display: none;
  }


</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('li.dropdown').click(function ()
    {
      $('li.dropdown').find('ul').hide();
      $(this).find('ul').show();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to get all the li elements that are like the one that you have clicked, but excluding the current clicked one, and hide them.

```
$(".dropdown a").not(this).hide();
```

I've created a snippet in JsFiddle, kindly check it out and let me know if this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/V45Ux/

Comment: please explain to me more about the behavior that you want to have here, so I can help you.